# Using a base enum as a default for dependent enums

Tags: java, enums

I'm working on a client that uses a standardised web service, however one of the vendors behaves in a slightly different way such that we must take account of these behaviours. To do this we have been using an enum:

```
public enum ServiceProviderType {
    FOO, BAR;

    public ServiceProviderType checkService(String url) {
        if (url.equals("http://www.example.com")) {
            return ServiceProviderType.FOO;
        } else {
            return ServiceProviderType.BAR;
        }
    }
}
```

The difference in these behaviours also differ according to what we request from the service, eg we might request a layer and want that layer coloured red, but know that BAR and FOO services represent RGB values differently. To do this we've created another enum that stores the properties we want for each layer in the service.

```
public enum LayerServiceProviderType {
    FOO("#ff0000"),
    BAR("#ff5555");

    private String colour;

    public ServiceProviderType(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public ServiceProviderType checkService(String url) {
        if (url.equals("http://www.example.com")) {
            return ServiceProviderType.FOO
        } else {
            return ServiceProviderType.BAR;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine except for when we want to handle multiple layers and treat them as all being derivative of the same base enum. Essentially we want to handle Layer1ServiceProviderType.BAR as being equivalent to Layer2ServiceProviderType.BAR. But we can't subclass enums, and even attempting to do so seems to break all kinds of sound design principles.

My first thought was to have an interface which contains an enum:

```
interface ServiceProvider {
    ServiceProviderType {FOO, BAR};

    ServiceProviderType getServiceProviderType();

    ServiceProvider checkService(String url);
}

public enum LayerServiceProvider implements ServiceProvider {
    FOO (ServiceProviderType.FOO, "#ff0000"),
    BAR (ServiceProviderType.BAR, "#ff0000");

    public LayerServiceProvider(ServiceProviderType serviceProviderType, String colour) {
        this.serviceProviderType = serviceProviderType;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceProviderType getServiceProviderType() {
        return this.serviceProviderType;
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceProvider checkService(String url) {
        if (url.equals("http://www.example.com")) {
            return LayerServiceProviderType.FOO
        } else {
            return LayerServiceProviderType.BAR;
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems overwrought to me to have an enum with in an enum that each hold the same range of values. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just add `colour` to `ServiceProviderType`?

Comment: `colour` and other variables won't be common to every `ServiceProviderType` - variables will change according to what we request from the service provider. The commonality is the enumeration.

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what the problem is that you're having.  This isn't really a question about enums nearly as much as it is about problem domain specification and model design.  "A poorly designed API can ruin a class forever" -- J. Bloch.  Maybe an enum is an elegant way to go (strategy enums are a thing), but perhaps not.  I am not familiar enough with your project to know how to help.

Comment: @scottb - In some cases the logic of differentiating between service providers is specific to the implementation of those service providers - eg depending on the layer we are requesting from the service. However in some cases the behaviour is generic. The strategy enum pattern solves my problem, but does this by duplicating the FOO, BAR values inside the nested enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is what you're looking for.

Used with an enum, it basically allows adding enum-dependent logic without using `switch` statements.

Example:

```
public enum ServiceProviderType {
    FOO {
        @Override public <T> T apply(Action<T> action) { return action.doFoo(); }
    },
    BAR {
        @Override public <T> T apply(Action<T> action) { return action.doBar(); }
    };

    public interface Action<T> {
        T doFoo();
        T doBar();
    }

    public abstract <T> T apply(Action<T> action);

    public static ServiceProviderType checkService(String url) {
        if (url.equals("http://www.example.com"))
            return FOO;
        return BAR;
    }
}

public class LayerServiceProviderType implements ServiceProviderType.Action<String> {
    @Override
    public String doFoo() {
        return "#ff0000";
    }
    @Override
    public String doBar() {
        return "#ff0000";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceProviderType type = ServiceProviderType.checkService("");

        String colour = type.apply(new LayerServiceProviderType());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this pattern, but I wonder how it works in the case where LayerServiceProviderType needs to return multiple variables. Such as a case where I might need to have a `colour` variable and a `name` variable (and many more).

Comment: In that case, you can think of the `Layer...` class above as a *factory class*, returning an object with the set of getters methods in question. It's not restricted to be just getter methods; it could be behavioral methods, making this more like the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), basically using the "factory" to obtain an enum-dependent "strategy".